# Nuxt class-based services architecture (register globally; vs manual import)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, service, architecture, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt app I'm registering app services in a plugin file (e.g. `/plugins/services.js`) like this...

```
import FeatureOneService from '@/services/feature-one-service.js'
import FeatureTwoService from '@/services/feature-two-service.js'
import FeatureThreeService from '@/services/feature-three-service.js'
import FeatureFourService from '@/services/feature-four-service.js'
import FeatureFiveService from '@/services/feature-five-service.js'

export default (ctx, inject) => {
  inject('feature1', new FeatureOneService(ctx))
  inject('feature2', new FeatureTwoService(ctx))
  inject('feature3', new FeatureThreeService(ctx))
  inject('feature4', new FeatureFourService(ctx))
  inject('feature5', new FeatureFiveService(ctx))
}
```

After doing this I can access any of my service on vue instance like `this.$feature1.someMethod()`

It works but I've once concern, that is, this approach loads all services globally. So whatever page the user visits all these services must be loaded.

Now I've 20+ such services in my app and this does not seem optimal approach to me.

The other approach I was wondering is to export a singleton *instance* within each service class and import this class instance in any component which needs that service.

So basically in my service class (e.g. `feature-one-service.js`) I would do like to do it like this..

`export default new FeatureOneService()` <---- I'm not sure how to pass nuxt instance in a `.js` file?

and import it my component where it is required like so...

`import FeatureOneService from '@/services/feature-one-service.js'`

What approach do you think is most feasible? if its the second one, then how to pass nuxt instance to my singleton class?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, loading everything globally is not optimal in terms of performance.

You will need to either try to use JS files and pass down the Vue instance there.
Or use [mixins](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins), this is not optimal but it is pretty much the only solution in terms of reusability with Vue2.

Vue3 (composition API) brings [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html), which is a far better approach regarding reusability (thing React hooks).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling a lot with it and the only solution is probably to inject services to the global Vue instance at the component/page level during the initialisation (in created hook), another option is to do that in the middleware (or anywhere else where you have access to the nuxt context. Otherwise you won't be able to pass nuxt context to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I usually set up services as classes, call them where necessary, and pass in the properties of the context which the class depends on as constructor arguments.

So for example, a basic MeiliSearchService class might look like:

```
export class MeilisearchService {

  #client: MeiliSearch

  constructor($config: NuxtRuntimeConfig) {
    super()
    this.#client = new MeiliSearch({
      host: $config.services.meilisearch.host,
      apiKey: $config.services.meilisearch.key
    })
  }

  ...
  someMethod() {
    let doSomething = this.#client.method()
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Then wherever you need to use the service, just new up an instance (passing in whatever it needs) and make it available to the component.

```
data() {
  const meiliSearchService = new MeiliSearchService(this.$config)
  return {
    meiliSearchService,
    results,
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  search(query) {
    ...
    this.results = this.meiliSearchService.search(query)
    ...
  }
}
```

As I'm sure you know, some context properties are only [available in certain Nuxt life-cycle hooks](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/). I find most of what I need is available everywhere, including `$config`, `store`, `$route`, `$router` etc.

Don't forget about Vue's reactivity when using this approach. For example, using a getter method on your service class will return the most recent value only when explicitly called. You can't, for example, stick the getter method in a `computed()` property and expect reactivty.

```
<div v-for='result in latestSearchResults'>
  ...
</div>

...

computed: {
  latestSearchResults() {
    return this.#client.getLatestResults()
  }
}
```

Instead, call the method like:

```
methods: {
  getLatestResults() {
    return this.#client.getLatestResults()
  }
}
```